# StackOverflow exception on private properties field

Tags: c#, properties, stack-overflow

Can someone please tell me why I get `StackOverflowException` for the code below ?

```
    private float _voltageRange
    {
        get { return _voltageRange + ((10F/100F)*_voltageRange); }
        set { _voltageRange = value; }
    }
```

How can I fix this problem? Isn't it taht compiler will make a backing field automatically?

What I want to achive is returning the `_VoltageRange` plus 10% of itself.

Comment: I think the compiler only provides backing fields if you use the default getter/setter, e.g. { get; set; }

Comment: recursive calls is the problem / issue here

Comment: Aside from the issues due to recursion, why are you using `10F/100F` instead of `0.1F`?

Comment: Not what you ask about, but mathematically `_voltageRange + ((10F/100F)*_voltageRange);` is the same as `1.10F * _voltageRange` (from the distributive law).

Comment: @JonSenchyna came before me. But actually in the original code, the division `(10F/100F)` will be done compile-time, so that part is only a matter of readability of the code. What the compiler won't do, is figure out that `v + 0.1F*v` equals `(1F + 0.1F)*v`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both your getter and your setter call themselves recursively.

No, the compiler doesn't create a backing field for you automatically - not unless you use an automatically implemented property like this:

```
public float VoltageRange { get; set; }
```

Whenever you provide getter/setter bodies, you have to do it *all* yourself.

It sounds like you want:

```
private float _voltageRange;
private float VoltageRange
{
    get { return _voltageRange + ((10F/100F)*_voltageRange); }
    set { _voltageRange = value; }
}
```

Or more simply:

```
private float _voltageRange;
private float VoltageRange
{
    get { return (_voltageRange * 11) / 10; }
    set { _voltageRange = value; }
}
```

(Or just multiply by 1.1f, but that will have a little more possibility for data loss.)

Note that this is a pretty odd property - one where the value set isn't the same one that's retrieved. Normally this:

```
VoltageRange = VoltageRange;
```

would be a no-op. That's what most readers would *expect*.

It would probably be better to have two properties, like this:

```
private VoltageRange { get; set; }

private EffectiveVoltageRange { get { return VoltageRange * 1.1f; } }
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, its confusing me though, in the `get` I am returning a equation, I dont assign that value to anything, I cant see the connectio nbetween the `get` and `set` in my code, or its just how it goes!

Comment: @Sean87 - right returning the equation but in that equation you are calling your private field over and over again...hence stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to look like this and this will fix your problem

```
private float _voltageRange;

public float VoltageRange
{
  get { return _voltageRange + ((10F/100F)*_voltageRange); }
  set { _voltageRange = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what IL will look like when you execute your private property:

```
get__voltageRange:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  call        UserQuery.get__voltageRange
IL_0006:  ldc.r4      CD CC CC 3D 
IL_000B:  call        UserQuery.get__voltageRange
IL_0010:  mul         
IL_0011:  add         
IL_0012:  stloc.0     
IL_0013:  br.s        IL_0015
IL_0015:  ldloc.0     
IL_0016:  ret         

set__voltageRange:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  call        UserQuery.set__voltageRange
IL_0007:  nop         
IL_0008:  ret
```

You can clearly see now where the recursion happens in the calls